# Sending requests to rest webServices from swagger ends to 401 and unauthorized

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, swagger, spring-restcontroller

I am new in this project and I got a task to add some services to the project.
First I created a package `NCDM` beside other  Rest packages and created my class `NCDMMemberController`:

```
    package ir.anarestan.ipc.controller.NCDM;
    import ir.anarestan.ipc.controller.helper.NCDM.NCDMMemberDTO;
    import ir.anarestan.ipc.controller.helper.ResponseDTO;
    import ir.anarestan.ipc.service.NCDM.NCDMMemberService;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.mobile.device.Device;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

    import java.util.List;


    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(path = "/ncdmMember")
    public class NCDMMemberController {

private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NCDMMemberController.class);

@Autowired
private NCDMMemberService ncdmMemberService;

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/getMember", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/hal+json")
public Object get(@RequestBody NCDMMemberDTO memberDTO, Device device) {
    ResponseDTO responseDTO = new ResponseDTO();
    try {
        responseDTO.setSuccess(true);
        responseDTO.setHttpStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        responseDTO.setResponseBody(ncdmMemberService.getMemberByMemberIdAndImei(memberDTO));
        return responseDTO;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("error occurred!", e);
        responseDTO.setSuccess(false);
        responseDTO.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        responseDTO.setHttpStatus(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED.value());
        responseDTO.setResponseBody(null);
        return responseDTO;
    }
}

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveMember", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/hal+json")
public Object save(@RequestBody NCDMMemberDTO member, Device device) {
    ResponseDTO responseDTO = new ResponseDTO();
    try {
        ncdmMemberService.saveMember(member);
        responseDTO.setSuccess(true);
        responseDTO.setHttpStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        responseDTO.setResponseBody(null);
        return responseDTO;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("error occurred!", e);
        responseDTO.setSuccess(false);
        responseDTO.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        responseDTO.setHttpStatus(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED.value());
        responseDTO.setResponseBody(null);
        return responseDTO;
    }
}
}
```

but when I try to send request from swagger, I got the following response:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1579957861338,
  "status": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "path": "/ncdmMember/saveMember"
}
```

And that happen when sendig request to the previous services has no error.
Does anyone know what is the problem?Do I need to introduce my package/class somewhere?

And when I copy one of the written services to the privious classes everything is ok.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the spring security in the app and configure  the endpoints like whether it should be authenticate or not.If it is to be authenticated provide the proper token or so

Comment: @Avi thansk for your help, i checked my webSecurityConfig and i find out that i need to permit the requestes that contains my base URL defined in controller class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches and of course by the clues that answers gave me, i found out that my problem raised from SpringSecurity, and the only thing that i needed to do was just adding my base URL of the controller class to WebSecurityConfig as permitted URLs like below:

```
.antMatchers("/ncdmMember/**").permitAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

it is because, you've Spring Security set up in your project. Based on the type of Authentication (`OAuth2`, `Basic Auth`, `Digest Auth`,... etc.), you need to add securityScheme in your `Docket` bean defined as SwaggerConfiguration.

Example:

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).
    ... // more configurations
    .securitySchemes(/*List of Your SecuritySchemes*/)
    .build();
```

Then you can use Swagger Documentation's **Authorize** button. Below is an example of OAuth2

[image]

[image]

Comment: You were true, the problem was from springSecurity but i didnt solve it by the way you mentioned.
I dont know maybe it was possible to solve with the solution you said , but i resolved my problem by adding my base URL of controller class as permited URLs in WebSecurityConfig.
Anyway thank you for the clues you gave me to fix my problem

Comment: Okay. It depends on your use case. If you don't want to secure URLs, you can just remove security dependency from `pom.xml`. I hope you know by adding the base URL to permitted URLs, your APIs are not secured, which means without any authentication, you can access them through browser/client etc. I guess that is what you want. 
If you want to have your URLs protected, you can use the above solution. Happy Coding!